# I want to use a checkbox in a function - Maxscript

Tags: function, checkbox, 3dsmax, maxscript

My question is about maxscript.
Is it possible to use a checkbox in a function? this checkbox works correctly when it is not in the function.
but when it's in the function, it doesn't work, and this is the error :

-- Error occurred in anonymous codeblock; filename: G:_BN Scripts\Checkbox problem.ms; position: 307; line: 18
-- Syntax error: at ), expected while
--  In line:    )

**My code :**

```
rollout AK "AK" width:200 height:400
(   checkbox 'FlipF' "Flip Face"   pos:[77,69] 

fn flip=
   (
        on FlipF changed theState do
    (
        if theState then
        (
         $.EditablePoly.flipNormals 1
        )
        else
        (
            $.EditablePoly.flipNormals 0
        )
    )
        
    )   
flip()  
)
createDialog AK
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not like this, you break both what's allowed in the rollout clauses by trying to run a function in the top scope, and then you use special rollout handler syntax inside a function.

If you want this checkbox to affect what happens inside some other rollout handler (as per you comment), use its state, not its handler:

```
try destroyDialog AK catch()
rollout AK "AK"
(
    checkbox chxFlipFaces "Flip Faces"
    button btnConvertAndFlip "Convert and maybe flip"

    on btnConvertAndFlip pressed do with undo on
    (
        if not isKindOf $ Shape do return messageBox "No shape selected"
        convertToPoly $
        if chxFlipFaces.state do
        (
            polyop.setFaceSelection $ #all
            setCommandPanelTaskMode #modify
            subObjectLevel = 4
            $.flipNormals 1
            completeRedraw()
        )
    )
)
createDialog AK
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Actually this code is just a sample and I made it for my question. I want to affect an object(poly) that will be created in a function, and I have to place my checkbox in the function, because before and after that function I don't have access to that object.
For example, my function 1-converts a spline to an editable poly, 2- then add a modifier  to the editable poly and so on....
I want my checkbox will affect before adding the modifier. I mean after 1. and before 2
I hope I could explain what I mean :)

Comment: See the edit. The handler only executes when the checkbox changes, and you don't need it here, anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So we can't have a checkbox inside a function. I got it